# Scrapy returns only first result

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data from gelbeseiten.de (yellow pages in germany)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
  from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
  from scrapy.http import Request
  from scrapy.selector import Selector
  from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse


class GelbeseitenSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "gelbeseiten"
  allowed_domains = ["http://www.gelbeseiten.de"]
  start_urls = ['http://www.gelbeseiten.de/zoohandlungen/s1/alphabetisch']

  def parse(self, response):
    for adress in response.css('article'):
      #Strasse
      strasse = adress.xpath('//span[@itemprop="streetAddress"]//text()').extract_first()

      #Name
      name = adress.xpath('//span[@itemprop="name"]//text()').extract_first()

      #PLZ
      plz = adress.xpath('//span[@itemprop="postalCode"]//text()').extract_first()

      #Stadt
      stadt = adress.xpath('//span[@itemprop="addressLocality"]//text()').extract_first()

      yield {
        'name': name,
        'strasse': strasse,
        'plz': plz,
        'stadt': stadt,
      }
```

As the result i get 15 sets with always the same address but i think it should be 15 different addresses.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use absolute xpath expressions:

`adress.xpath('//span[@itemprop="streetAddress"]//text()')`

while should use relative to `address` (note leading dot in expression):

`adress.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="streetAddress"]//text()')`